# (DONE) Reopen request: How do you forgive/let go/move on from a bully ex employer

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[How do you forgive/let go/move on from a bully ex employer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/147271/how-do-you-forgive-let-go-move-on-from-a-bully-ex-employer/147281)

This got closed as off topic: questions require a goal we can address.

I've edited to make the goal clear by adding a sentence to the end of the question, stating the goal.

I'm hoping that if others agree, this will be voted to re-open. Or, we could get further edits to make the question acceptable.

I think it represents a valuable question for this site, worth investing some time in to in terms of edits (and answers!) since many employees get really hung up thinking about the problems in their old workplace. Having a question that discusses strategies to address that problem could help many people.

Comment: "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a mental health issue instead of a question about interpersonal workplace issues or behaviour in workplace-related scenarios." - what about that?

Comment: VTRO  it is absolutely workplace related, and boy can I relate

Comment: @Dukeling it is a workplace issue.  The OP is talking about something that was caused in the workplace, and wants to move on in the workplace.  There are good answers (and not just mine) and I think erring on the side of compassion couldn't hurt.

Comment: The edits are way better, and IMO make it answerable.  It is open now.

Comment: @RichardU Sure, it is "a workplace issue", but that doesn't necessarily mean it's on topic. That's why I specifically mentioned interpersonal / behaviour in the "instead" part. Interpersonal Skills SE has a policy about closing question where a mental health issue came about as a result of an interpersonal issue (and similar questions on every other site would probably also be closed), because they're not therapists. We aren't either.

Comment: @Dukeling we're not talking schizophrenia, clinical depression, BPD, NPD, or anything that actually rises to mental health.  This would be more inline with something that could be found in the 7 habits of highly effective people (work related) or "Who moved my cheese" (also work related) or any number of business related issues.  This isn't even rising to the level or something that would even require a therapist.

Comment: frustration with and dwelling on the past are normal issues, both in the workplace and generally. Fairly easily fixed through various strategies, no need for therapy.

Comment: We're workplace experts, but everything I read in the answers draw from experience or expertise with mental health that might not even be workplace-related at all. They do not draw on expertise specific to the workplace and can be applied pretty much word-for-word to similar non-workplace scenarios. I'm also not saying "they need therapy", but rather that the question just fundamentally doesn't belong here.

Comment: thats because I only gave one strategy, my personal strategy of giving the guy a kicking since he's no longer my boss, wouldn't be ideal in many locales and cultures.

Comment: @Dukeling so what's more important, adhering to the rules relentlessly, or helping someone?

Comment: @RichardU What's the point of rules if people don't follow them? If something's against the rules, it should be removed (closed / deleted). You're free to try to help them *as well* by pointing them somewhere more appropriate, posting a comment, posting an answer (before it's closed) or engaging with them in chat. If you're arguing that we should *change* the rules, or that this isn't against the rules to begin with, I disagree, but fair enough.

Comment: I agree with @Dukeling. The question could be "How do you forgive/let go/move on from a bully" and would have the same "Seek professional help", "Get a hobby", "Exercise", "Give it time", etc. This is a moving on or mental health issue. That said, if someone has mental health expertise and wants to answer, go for it. While I don't think we should provide medical advice, that doesn't seem to actually stop anyone.

Comment: @Dukeling What's the point in having laws if maximum sentences aren't universally given?  We have a bit of leeway, we have a bit of discretion, and someone is hurting.  We can bend the rules a bit from time to time to help someone.

Comment: Rules are just soft guidelines, mods interpret them however suits them, SE interprets them whatever... etc,.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere if we can help, we should help

Comment: I guess I don't see how the target question is any different than the one the same member posted earlier. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/139892/post-toxic-workplace-blues That one is Closed as off-topic.

Comment: @RichardU - thus we should never close any question. I'm okay with that.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I think it is substantially different. That question is really open ended, and specifically says "I'd like to hear from people who have been there" which to me, is a trigger for off topic. This question states a specific goal and asks how to achieve it. To me, that's the difference.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have always been of the opinion that if it comes down to a decision to close, or help someone if we can, we should always err on the side of compassion.

Comment: @dwizum beat me to it.  The first one, the OP seemed a bit raw, but still, it could have been answered.

Comment: I think there's clearly a gray area around off topic close reasons. There's also a gray area around if this is actually a "mental health" issue or not. We have a lot of questions from people who express that they've been frustrated or angry for a long time, and those don't get closed.

Comment: @RichardU - I agree. However many still rush to close questions without ever attempting to answer or help in any way. I'm not sure why this particular question would be any different.

Comment: @RichardU Unfortunately this leeway would apply to too many question askers, since people who ask for help usually need help. It would be comparable to completely ignoring all petty crime, because there are usually strong situational factors behind such crime (such as poverty). Of course locking people up for life also doesn't make sense. But then we're not banning people after having one of their questions closed, and we can still help them while closing the question, so I'm really struggling to understand your reasoning.

Comment: @RichardU "What's the point in having laws if maximum sentences aren't universally given" - did you mean "*are* universally given"? Because the opposite would be true for most countries.

Comment: @Dukeling Funny, I've been poor to the point of homelessness, and never found the need to commit crimes.  That said, if help isn't our primary concern, what is?

Comment: Help is our primary concern. I'm all for giving the benefit of the doubt to questions approaching the edge.

Comment: @RichardU Comparably, I've had intrapersonal issues related to the workplace, yet I've found ways to deal with them other than asking an off-topic question here. We're here to help with a specific subset of problems. We have to draw the line somewhere otherwise we'd soon be helping create recipes for chefs, write code, apply for work visas, translate things, give legal advice, deal with serious mental health issues (often in dangerous ways, because most of us have no business advising on that) and whatever else. Maybe that makes sense under some philosophy, but it's not what we're doing here.

Comment: @Dukeling the slippery slope is a logical fallacy.  It's not an either/or thing.  There is nuance, and there are gray areas.  Personally, I no longer vote to close any questions.  Some people put answers in the comments.  If we err on the side of closing things unnecessarily, we not only deprive that user, but any user with similar problems, of help

Comment: @RichardU I said "We have to draw the line **somewhere**". We seem to be on the same page about that part at least (not that it seemed like this from some of your earlier comments), so I'm not sure what you're arguing about at this point. The only difference is on which side of this type of question we think the line should be drawn or how much leeway should be given. But frankly this seems so far outside our domain of expertise that I'm rather surprised anyone's even arguing about it (unless the argument were just to have come from the belief that we should close pretty much **nothing**).

Comment: @Dukeling I think if we can answer a question, we should.  Where I draw the line is if it's unrelated to TWP, or dangerous to answer.  Otherwise, I won't VTC.

In cases where it's beyond a non-professional's ability to answer, we should still include a comment to seek professional help, even if we close it.

Comment: Just want to say thanks to everyone for discussing in comments. It's always nice to see people willing to express their opinions on things like this in a helpful and respectful manner.

Comment: @dwizum don't let the word get out.  Pretty soon people might start to think we are actually nice.