# Reopen request: Sent technical test that was impossible, other candidates completed it

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Sent technical test that was impossible, other candidates completed it](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/148227/sent-technical-test-that-was-impossible-other-candidates-completed-it/148229)

This question was just put on hold with the "questions require a goal we can address" reason. I'm not sure I agree with that, because the question has a clearly stated goal in bold:

**I feel like I need closure, but the employer is not explaining this test result to me. How should I help myself move on?**

We know lots of people coming to this site struggle with being rejected in interviews, and/or struggle with how to interpret what they're told when they are rejected. Questions like this may fall in to a gray area in the strict sense, but I do think there's a lot of potential value in them.

Further, it's a highly upvoted question with many highly upvoted answers that have interesting comments. I feel like it's a bit of a shame to shut it down.

I have voted to reopen and would ask others to as well if they agree.

Comment: I would VTRO if we somehow could rephrase the actual question to remove the "How should I..." part, as I feel it is highly *"asking us to make a choice for OP"*

Comment: @DarkCygnus the edit button is on the bottom, mr somebody :D

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica I know Richard :0) but I'm currently with a kinda critical task here at work... when I get free I surely will take an edit.

Comment: @DarkCygnus No worries, just some friendly ribbing.  :D

Comment: I'm thinking about that sort of edit too. I feel like the acceptance of wording in situations like this is a little arbitrary. What about something like "What strategies work in order to help me move on?" Or, "how should I respond to the employer's lack of explanation?"

Comment: @dwizum I like your first option better (I try to avoid the "should" word as it happens to be a CV magnet...) I see the post was edited to a state I consider worthy of a VTRO... one more to go

Comment: vtro and its open

Comment: I still maintain that [questions exclusively about intrapersonal issues are off topic](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6418/done-reopen-request-how-do-you-forgive-let-go-move-on-from-a-bully-ex-employe#comment20632_6418). But more than that I feel this should be closed as a duplicate of one of the many canonical posts we don't have (which may simply ask how to handle failing a technical interview test and cover all aspects of that).

Comment: @Dukeling if it effects the workplace, then it's not exclusively an interpersonal issue, and the answers we give here would be shut down and deleted over there anyway.

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica I meant **intra**-personal, not interpersonal, as in taking place inside the mind.

Comment: @Dukeling sorry, went all dyslexic on that. one.